# Why can't I display the contents of the array?

Tags: c#

```
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){ Console.Writeline(Upticket(i)); };
```

Up ticket is the name of the array. It says "UpTicket" is not null here and method name expected even though this exact code worked previously in the exact same code file.

Comment: It seems you confused `Writeline` with `WriteLine` (and possibly also `Upticket` with `UpTicket`), and also `(i)` with `[i]` - the former would be VB.NET syntax, not C#.

Comment: If `Upticket` is an array, then the proper syntax is to use `[` instead of `(` : `Upticket[i]`

Comment: Thank you. It seems I had to use [] instead of ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [] to access elements in an array

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < Upticket.Length; i++) {
    Console.Writeline(Upticket[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var someArray = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(someArray[i]);
}
```

[you'll get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fszgP.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).